# Kafka consumer disconnect - Disconnected (after 684744ms in state UP)

Tags: python-3.x, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I have a problem in my kafka consumer.
When I run my consumer in localhost he run correctly, but when I run my consumer in another environment he show this error

> %6|1629836068.968|rdkafka#consumer-1| [thrd:ssl://kafka-events:11101/12101]:ssl://kafka-events:11101/12101: Disconnected (after 684744ms in state UP)

I don't know whats the root cause of this error.

My kafka consumer are developed in python 3 with confluent kafka DeserializingConsumer.